# This attempt at Project Euler fails at the 16th digit onward.

Tags: c++, optimization

Find the sum of the digits of 2^1000

Using functions, user inputs base and exponent, such as 4^5 (base 4, exponent 5).

If one compares the value and the digits outputted in the vector, it fails beginning in the 16th place.

My attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 


double Integer() {
    double m,o;  
    double n; 

    cout<<"Enter Base: ";
    cin>>m; 
    cout<<"Enter Exponent: ";
    cin>>o; 

    n= pow(m,o);

    cout.precision(302); 

    cout << "The Answer is: " << n << endl; 

    return n;
}

void SumoftheDigits(double n) { 

    double x, q, w=0, r, d;
    int length = r = (log(n)/ log(10)) + 1;

    vector<double> v1;

    modf((n/pow(10,r)),&x);

    while (r != 0) {

        q = modf( (n/pow(10,r-1)), &x);
        n -= x*pow(10,r-1);

        r--;
        d = x;

        v1.push_back(d);

    }

    for(vector<double>::iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it){
            cout << *it << " ";
    } 

    cout << endl; 

    int i;
    long long int Sum = 0; 

    while (i != v1.size()) {
        Sum += v1[i]; 
        i++;
    } 

    cout << "The Sum of the Digits is: " << Sum << endl; 

} 

int main() {

    double n = Integer(); 

    SumoftheDigits(n); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A IEEE-754 `double` only provides about 16 significant decimal digits. I don't think your method is going to work. You could cheat and use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^1000).

Comment: Your code really has some _serious_ problems.  Naming conventions, indentation issues, not using += or that stuff, no comments or anything.  If you just took the time to comment your code, format it properly, and make it readable, you'd likely already know what the problem is.

Comment: I indented it so that you can see it as code, and please describe them, I'm merely a novice.

Comment: thanks for whoever or whatever cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point types (e.g. `float` and `double`) have limited precision, so you can't use them to calculate large numbers such as values around 2^1000. There will be inaccuracies as you have seen.

You will need to use integer methods to do this. Normal integers can't represent numbers as large as 2^1000, so it will take a little more work. For example, you can represent each digit separately in an array, and implement long multiplication such as you learned in school.

There are also libraries such as GMP that can represent very large integers (bound only by your computer's memory), which will make this an easy task.

Comment: @AndyJean: If you're referring to my mention of arrays, then yes vectors are great and you should prefer them.